# Multiplying column and skipping blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba7

I need to multiply column and it has to skip blank range, I need formula or VBA for this case.
For example, if Range A1 having value 2, range C1 = 3, range E1 is blank, range G1 = 1, Range I1 = 3 & K1 is blank, the answer is 2 ×3 ×1 ×3 = 18. I just need a solution to ignore columns having blank value either formula or VBA code

I tried to multiply from range A1×C1×E1×G1×I1×K1, I got answer as 0 since it is considering blank column as 0.

Comment: Show a small sample grid of typical data, including the result you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this case, =Product is the perfect formula

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).